# Add & Edit in same Vuejs Page

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuetify.js

Now i have a List page with 2 Buttons (Create,Edit)
Like this :

```
    <v-btn color="primary" dark class="mb-2" @click="editItem(new Object())">Create</v-btn>
      </v-toolbar>
    </template>
    <template v-slot:item.action="{ item }">
      <v-icon small class="mr-2" @click="editItem(item)">edit</v-icon>
```

And in another page AddEdit.vue

i have bind the data using V-model
Like this :

```
  <v-text-field v-model="SelectedUnit.bedrooms" label="No. Of Bedrooms"></v-text-field>

  <v-text-field v-model="SelectedUnit.bathrooms" label="No. Of Bathrooms"></v-text-field>

  <v-text-field v-model="SelectedUnit.area" label="Area"></v-text-field>

  <v-text-field v-model="SelectedUnit.builtArea" label="builtArea"></v-text-field>

  <v-text-field v-model="SelectedUnit.landArea" label="land Area"></v-text-field>


  <v-text-field v-model="SelectedUnit.address.addressLine1" label="adress Line 1"></v-text-field>
```

i can bind the Data when i press Edit except SelectedUnit.address.addressLine1
and if i used v-for i can bind the data for SelectedUnit.address.addressLine1

Problem is: when i use V-for the edit button works well
but when i press create i get alot of erros in the console and nothing draw in my screen

Comment: Could you provide the errors you're getting in the console? It's a little harder to diagnose the problem without it.

Comment: vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'addressLine1' of undefined"

found in

---> <UnitDetails>
       <UnitsList> at src/components/Compound/UnitsList.vue
         <VContent>
           <VApp>
             <App> at src/App.vue
               <Root>

Comment: what i want to do is have a form which allows me to edit data that i send when i press Edit, OR create new object and i add the data in it

Comment: Can you share your edit and/or add logic from the component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you are passing `new Object()` to your `editItem` method. I'm assuming that you assign that value `SelectedUnit` in that method, which is causing the error.

The problem is that this sets the nested object `address` to undefined. So when you try and read `addressLine1` from an undefined object, it will throw an error.

I suggest setting `SelectedUnit` to a blank version of itself inside the edit method. Something like this.

```
this.SelectedUnit = {
  address: {
    addressLine1: '',
    ...
  },
  bedrooms: '',
  ...
}
```